# Consumir Webservice Javascript con fetch

Tags: javascript, webservice

Quiero consumir un *Webservice*, pero debo enviar usuario y contraseña, aún no encuentro algún ejemplo. Este es mi código:

```
fetch('URL')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(console.log);
```

Por *Postman* envío los parámetros en *Body* y la opción *raw*

```
{
  "usuario":"USU_PRUEBA",
  "passwor":"12345678"
}
```

¿Cómo puedo integrar eso al método?

Comment: En la misma [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#enviando_datos_json) de `fetch` viene un ejemplo de como enviar un JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si debes enviar un usuario y contraseña para obtener algo, lo primero a considerar es el método. En tu ejemplo, es un `GET`, pero, por como lo planteas, debería ser un `POST`.

```javascript
const tuData = {
  "usuario":"USU_PRUEBA",
  "passwor":"12345678"
}

fetch('URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(tuData), // tu data JSON se convierte en TEXTO
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(res => res.json()) // se obtiene respuesta y se parsea a JSON.
.then(res => console.log('Respuesta: ', res));
.catch(err => console.error('Error:', err));
```

Verifica de igual forma en Postman utilizando el método `POST` qué ocurre.

Coméntanos como te va, saludos!